# Changing predicates at runtime

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose you have different predicates (function objects with initial state in this particular case) that you use with STL algorithms (`copy_if` ,`sort` etc...). Thing is that predicates can change at runtime by configuration change or user input. I've thought using polymorphism and virtual `operator()`, then settled on a `std::function` solution like this (this puts me in C++11 realm but that's okay)

```
struct PlainFilter {
    PlainFilter(string filter):m_filter(filter)
    {}
    bool operator() (const string& toMatch)
    {one way}
};
struct AcronymFilter {
    AcronymFilter (string filter):m_filter(filter)
    {}
    bool operator() (const string& toMatch)
    {a different way}
};

enum FilterTypes {plain,acronym};

vector<string> FilterStuff(string filter, vector<string> in)
{
     vector<string> out;
     std::function<bool(const string&)> foo;

     if( filterType == plain)
         foo = PlainFilter(filter);
     else if( filterType == acronym)
         foo = AcronymFilter(filter);

     copy_if(in.begin(),in.end(),back_inserter(out),foo);
     return out;
}
```

Is this good?

I'd rather avoid that if else statements everytime I need to filter strings since filter type might change once or none at all throughout the lifetime of the program.
 Any other different take on the problem is also welcome..

Comment: Your code is illegible. Just saying.

Comment: Yeah wrote in a haste .Tabified for you. You can answer now :)

Comment: One thing wrong leaps to mind immediately: What do you expect `foo` to be (and thus do) for that `copy_if` statement at the tail of `FilterStuff` if `filterType` is *neither* `plain` nor `acronym`?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to do this, but this is what polymorphism is for. Your code is simplified, *and* you don't have to remember to add a new `case` or `else if` for any new filters you dream up in every place it could be used.

```
struct IFilter
{
    virtual bool operator()(const std::string &) const = 0;
};

struct PlainFilter : public IFilter
{
    virtual bool operator()(const std::string &filter) const override
    {
        // do something
    }
};

struct AcronymFilter : public IFilter
{
    virtual bool operator()(const std::string &filter) const override
    {
        // do something else
    }
};


std::vector<std::string> FilterStuff(const IFilter &filter, const std::vector<std::string> &in)
{
    std::vector<std::string> out;
    std::copy_if(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out), filter);

    return out;
}
```

However, I personally would implement `FilterStuff` differently. You're taking `string`s from one `vector` and copying them to another, and then presumably another piece of code is going to iterate over that new `vector` and do something with those filtered `string`s. Consider instead a design that takes a filter *and* the "do something with it" function:

```
void EnumerateStuff(const IFilter &filter, const std::vector<std::string> &in,
                    std::function<void(std::string)> callback)
{
    for (const auto &s : in)
    {
        if (filter(s))
        {
            callback(s);
        }
    }
}
```

`FilterStuff` can now be written in terms of `EnumerateStuff`, if it's really necessary to have a filtered copy:

```
std::vector<std::string> FilterStuff(const IFilter &filter, const std::vector<std::string> &in)
{
    std::vector<std::string> out;

    EnumerateStuff(filter, in,
        [&](const std::string &s)
        {
            out.push_back(s);
        });

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Won't the first solution slice the filter and give error for calling abstract function? Also i need to pass initial state to the filter function. Are you suggesting a setter method in the base IFilter in that case (States are same for all filter objects). Since I was setting the state in the constructor, I was creating a new functor hence the if else...

Comment: No, there will be no slicing since you're passing a reference and not an object. As for initializing your filter's state, leave it that as part of the concrete filter's constructor's job.

Comment: My bad. I've noticed it after commenting.Then again there is the decision to how to pick which concrete filter to be constructed every time when stuff is going to be filtered (Filtering criteria changes not the filter type). In order not to lookup the filter type every time, the filter object should be stored and there should be some means to pass the criteria, so the requirement for setter method.Or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

what is a `filterType` variable in your example? I guess some configurable parameter for your application/algorithm??

anyway, I'd propose the following:

1) collect all configurable parameters into a structure:

```
class configuration
{
public:
    /// Type of predicate functor
    typedef std::function<bool(const std::string&)> predicate_type;

    struct plain_filter { /* your implementation */ };
    struct acronym_filter { /* your implementation */ };

    /// Type of predicate to use
    enum class predicate_type { plain, acronym };

    /// Set predicate
    void set_filter_kind(const predicate_type ft)
    {
        switch (ft)
        {
        case predicate_type::plain:
            m_predicate = plain_filter();
            break;
        case predicate_type::acronym:
            m_predicate = acronym_filter();
            break;
        default:
            assert(!"Invalid filter type");
        }
    }

    /// Get filter to be used by algorithms
    /// \todo Consider to return a const reference instead of copy,
    /// but make sure your filters are state-less (as expected by STL slgorithms)
    decltype(m_predicate) use_filter() const
    {
        return m_predicate;
    }

    // other configuration parameters/methods

private:
    predicate_type m_predicate;
};
```

2) fill an instance of `configuration` from command-line options, config file, or user input. Make this instance visible to all required parts of your code (for example make it the member of your `application` class and provide a method to (read-only) access it or smth like this...)

3) use configuration data in your algorithms

```
std::vector<string> filter_stuff(string filter, const std::vector<string>& in)
{
    std::vector<string> out;
    std::copy_if(
        begin(in)
      , end(in)
      , std::back_inserter(out)
      , application().get_config().use_filter()
      );
    return out;
}
```

PS: btw, pass `in` parameter via reference (or rvalue reference)... I'm really in doubt that you need a copy (pass it by value)

Comment: Yes that was a blunder. In the actual code it's done on a class member that was my error while writing the example.your answer is good but the filter needs a parameter to filter the vector against.I was giving it at the constructor for filter functors hence the if..else

Answer (score 0):

Since `filterType` is a runtime value, you're going to have some kind of selection going on here.  There's your `if`'s, a `switch`, or an array lookup.  I like the `switch` best, the array lookup requires more complex types and isn't any faster once the optimizer gets through with it. Also I'd pass the initializers by `const &` not by value just on reflex.

That said, I think your method's fine.  Another way to do it:

```
bool plain_string_test(const string& filter, const string& candidate) 
{  /* ... one way ... */ }

bool acronym_string_test(const string& filter, const string& candidate)
{  /* ... or another ... */ }

enum FilterTypes {plain,acronym};

vector<string> FilterStuff(string filter, vector<string> in)
{
     vector<string> out;
     std::function<bool(const string&, const string&)> filtermethod;

     switch(filterType) {
     default: throw some_domain_error(some_constructor_here);

     case plain:      filtermethod = plain_string_test;         break;
     case acronym:    filtermethod = acronym_string_test;       break;

     }

     copy_if(in.begin(),in.end(),back_inserter(out), 
         [&filtermethod, &filter](const string& candidate) -> bool
             { return filtermethod(filter,candidate); }
     return out;
}
```

I do like this one better; it eliminates some type scaffolding and some copying and makes the string tests more reusable (or also elminates some function scaffolding).  Here you might be able to get better value from a static array of functions, it'd probably depend on context.

keyboard-to-editbox warning, I haven't tested this code but I do believe it's at least correct enough for communication.

Comment: I've learned my lesson not to hastily give examples here, since the users can be pretty pedantic. I think it's better to cache filtermethod (since this is a class method in reality) and only change it when the user actually changes filter to avoid checking for filtertype everytime something needs to be filtered.Thanks for the answer though